# How to embed YouTube video with a full screen button enabled on Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I tried all available methods so far except those that I would have to eject my app from Expo. I could not try 'react-native-youtube' because it required me to eject from Expo. I also tried 'react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video' but it seems to require ejecting as well, although it did not explicitly mentioned.

I simply tried to embed YouTube by using react native's

```
chooseVideo = () => {
        const re = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*?[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig;
        const embedVideo = this.state.url.replace(re, 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?modestbranding=1&loop=1&playlist=$1&showinfo=0');
```

...

```
<WebView
    style={{width: '100%', height: undefined, aspectRatio: 16 / 9}}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    source={{uri: this.props.video}}
/>
```

It shows a full screen button, but it is disabled, so I cannot press it.

I also tried using iframe. It did not work.

```
<WebView
        style={{width: '100%', height: undefined, aspectRatio: 16 / 9}}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{ html: "<html><body><iframe width="560" height="315" src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/'" + this.props.videoId + "' frameBorder='0' allowFullScreen='allowFullScreen'></iframe></body></html>"}}
/>
```

iframe does not work either.

I am testing on Android platforms using Expo.

Comment: Same issue?: https://forums.expo.io/t/youtube-video-does-not-allow-full-screen-mode-through-the-webview-component/11407 Existing issue ticket: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/react-native-youtube

Comment: @Morrison Chang Yes. So is the only thing I can do is just waiting?

Comment: The most capability is writing in the native framework (Java/Kotlin or Swift/ObjC) and even then there are limitations. Using a third party framework adds even more. Unless you are able to modify Expo to do what you want, all you can do wait (but note how long the ticket has been open).

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Native Youtube Iframe that is compatible with Expo.

https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe

The video player has a full screen button.

Some limitations :

- There is [an open issue](https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe/issues/45) about listening for fullscreen requests on iOS if you want to trigger side effects. The library owner has requested some help.
- There is now way to enforce fullscreen at startup.

If you need a workaround for these issues you can check this answer that propose to make a full screen view instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188272/9927519